# Nested Itemscontrols data binding to the same Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

This may be a dupe, but I couldn't find anything in an hour or so of searching and reading MSDN.

I'm making a 2D tile-based game and have an ItemsControl bound to a list of Tiles (C# class). This works great.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Board.Rows}" Columns="{Binding Board.Columns}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Tile}">
            <Grid x:Name="tileGrid" Background="{Binding TileImage}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
<ItemsControl>
```

There's an inner 5x5 Grid for each Tile since I need to be able to place units at various locations on each Tile. Each `Tile` contains a `List<Location>` where there is a unit, which I want to place on that Grid.

```
<Grid x:Name="tileGrid" Background="{Binding TileImage}">
    <ColumnDefinition snipped - there's 5 columns and 5 rows>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
                <Image Source="unit.bmp"
                        Grid.Column="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ColumnConverter}}"
                        Grid.Row="{Binding Converter={StaticResource RowConverter}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Where ColumnConverter and RowConverter just get the column index from a Location.

The problem is that I can't bind to tileGrid's Column and Row from inside the ItemsControl. Some people have suggested putting the Grid inside the Locations ItemsControl, but that doesn't work because it needs to be a child of the outer Tiles ItemsControl.

What can I do?

Comment: Which grid do you mean as the outer grid? The UniformGrid?

Comment: I've clarified in the question. I want the collection of Locations to be positioned within the 5x5 tileGrid, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I repeat previous suggestions, but you should use tileGrid as ItemsPanel for Locations ItemsControl and make this ItemsControl to be a child of Tiles ItemsControl. I don't understand why it is impossible?

Perhaps you need to do something with tileGrid within DataTemplate. So, I think is is possible to do the same for ItemsControl.

I also can assume that there are additional ColumnDefinitions or RowDefinitions in tileGrid. In this way you can use another Grid inside Locations and bind its definitions with tileGrid using [IsSharedSizeScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx) and [SharedSizeGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup.aspx)

Comment: The issue I was having with that is that tileGrid also contains other elements that need to be positioned. Trying that gives me the following error: "Cannot explicitly modify Children collection of Panel used as ItemsPanel for ItemsControl. ItemsControl generates child elements for Panel."

Comment: This exception occurs because Panel used as ItemsPanel cannot contain elements explicitly. Rachel pointed well about using ItemContainerStyle instead of ItemTemplate for position properties. I think you can stay with tilePanel in DataTemplate of Locations and use another Grid as ItemsPanel of Tiles. You also need to use shared size scopes to combine panels in ItemControl(s).

Answer (score 0):

Set the Grid.Column and Grid.Row in the ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle, not in the DataTemplate. Each item is wrapped in a ContentPresenter so the Grid.Column and Grid.Row are not getting applied properly